# simple_html_dom - read html page, two arrays

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

This is my entire code

```
// include the scrapper 
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// connect the page for scrapping
$html = file_get_html('http://www.niagarafallsreview.ca/news/local');

// make empty arrays
$headlines = array();
$links = array();

// look for 'h' headings on page
foreach($html->find('h1') as $header) {
    $headlines[] = $header->plaintext;
}

// look for 'a' links that start with 'http://www.niagarafallsreview.ca/2016/04/'
foreach($html->find('a[href^="http://www.niagarafallsreview.ca/2016/04/"]')  as $link) {
    $links[] = $link->href;
}

// trim the headlines because one on top and bottom were not needed
$output = array_slice($headlines, 1, -1); 

// for each header output a nice list of the headers 
foreach ($output as $headers){
    echo "< a href='#'>$headers</a>" . "<br />";
}

// make sure the links are unique and no doubles are found
$result = array_unique($links);

// for each link output it in a nice list
foreach ($result as $linkk){
    echo "<a href='$linkk'>$linkk</a>" . "<br />";
}
```

this code will produce the headings in a nice list, and will also produce a nice list of the links.

My problem is that i need to combine them, i would like the $header to be the text of the href, and the link in the href to be the $linkk

like this..

```
< a href ='$linkk'>$headers</a>
```

I dont know how to do this as i have two foreach statements. I tried to combine them but i was unsuccessful.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you show source html? Why do you think that arrays have the same length and correspond one to another?

Comment: the source is the connected page 5th line down.

If i echo out the arrays by themselves they are indexed properly

Comment: could you solve the problem? Did our answers help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the foreach you are looking for:

```
foreach($output as $i=>$headers) {
  $linkk = $result[$i];

  echo "< a href='$linkk'>$headers</a>" . "<br />";
}
```

This assumes the arrays have the same length and also the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// include the scrapper 
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// connect the page for scrapping
$html = file_get_html('http://www.niagarafallsreview.ca/news/local');

// make empty arrays
$headlines = array();
$links = array();

// look for 'h' headings on page
foreach($html->find('h1') as $header) {
    $headlines[] = $header->plaintext;
}

// look for 'a' links that start with 'http://www.niagarafallsreview.ca/2016/04/'
foreach($html->find('a[href^="http://www.niagarafallsreview.ca/2016/04/"]')  as $link) {
    $links[] = $link->href;
}

// trim the headlines because one on top and bottom were not needed
$output = array_slice($headlines, 1, -1); 

// make sure the links are unique and no doubles are found
$result = array_unique($links);

// for each link output it in a nice list
foreach ($result as $i=>$linkk) {
    $headline = isset($output[$i]) ? $output[$i] : '(empty)';
    echo "<a href='$linkk'>$headline</a>" . "<br />";
}
```